# ASP.NET MVC creating paypal webhook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using REST API SDK for Dotnet V2 [github link](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-DotNet-SDK) to integrate with PayPal orders create and capture it's working fine.

I'm trying now to implement the webhook, already spent lots of hours trying to find out how to create a controller to receive PayPal webhooks to update my orders status but not able to find solution.

Is there a .net documentation or sample code on how to create a webhook in .NET?

This is my vb.net code to create and capture orders

```
Private Shared Function BuildRequestBody() As OrderRequest
    Dim orderRequest As OrderRequest = New OrderRequest() With {
    .CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",
    .ApplicationContext = New ApplicationContext With {
        .BrandName = "EXAMPLE INC",
        .LandingPage = "BILLING",
        .CancelUrl = "https://XXX/Home/CancelUrl",
        .ReturnUrl = "https://XXX/Home/CaptureOrder",
        .UserAction = "CONTINUE",
        .ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
    },
    .PurchaseUnits = New List(Of PurchaseUnitRequest) From {
        New PurchaseUnitRequest With {
            .ReferenceId = "PUHF",
            .Description = "Sporting Goods",
            .CustomId = "CUST-HighFashions",
            .SoftDescriptor = "HighFashions",
            .AmountWithBreakdown = New AmountWithBreakdown With {
                .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                .Value = "220.00",
                .AmountBreakdown = New AmountBreakdown With {
                    .ItemTotal = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "180.00"
                    },
                    .Shipping = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "20.00"
                    },
                    .Handling = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "10.00"
                    },
                    .TaxTotal = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "20.00"
                    },
                    .ShippingDiscount = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "10.00"
                    }
                }
            },
            .Items = New List(Of Item) From {
                New Item With {
                    .Name = "T-shirt",
                    .Description = "Green XL",
                    .Sku = "sku01",
                    .UnitAmount = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "90.00"
                    },
                    .Tax = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "10.00"
                    },
                    .Quantity = "1",
                    .Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                },
                New Item With {
                    .Name = "Shoes",
                    .Description = "Running, Size 10.5",
                    .Sku = "sku02",
                    .UnitAmount = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "45.00"
                    },
                    .Tax = New Money With {
                        .CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        .Value = "5.00"
                    },
                    .Quantity = "2",
                    .Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                }
            },
            .ShippingDetail = New ShippingDetail With {
                .Name = New Name With {
                    .FullName = "John Doe"
                },
                .AddressPortable = New AddressPortable With {
                    .AddressLine1 = "123 Townsend St",
                    .AddressLine2 = "Floor 6",
                    .AdminArea2 = "San Francisco",
                    .AdminArea1 = "CA",
                    .PostalCode = "94107",
                    .CountryCode = "US"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    Return orderRequest
End Function

Public Shared Function CreateOrder(ByVal Optional d As Boolean = False) As HttpResponse
    Debug.WriteLine("Create Order with minimum payload..")
    Dim request = New OrdersCreateRequest()
    request.Headers.Add("prefer", "return=representation")
    request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody())

    Dim response = Task.Run(Async Function() Await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request)).Result

    If d Then
        Dim result = response.Result(Of Order)()
        Debug.WriteLine($"Status: {result.Status}")
        Debug.WriteLine($"Order Id: {result.Id}")
        Debug.WriteLine($"Intent: {result.CheckoutPaymentIntent}")
        Debug.WriteLine("Links:")

        For Each link As LinkDescription In result.Links
            Debug.WriteLine(vbTab & $"{link.Rel}: {link.Href}" & vbTab & $"Call Type: {link.Method}")
        Next

        Dim amount As AmountWithBreakdown = result.PurchaseUnits(0).AmountWithBreakdown
        Debug.WriteLine($"Total Amount: {amount.CurrencyCode} {amount.Value}")
    End If

    Return response
End Function

Public Shared Function CaptureOrder(ByVal OrderId As String, ByVal Optional d As Boolean = False) As HttpResponse
    Dim request = New OrdersCaptureRequest(OrderId)
    request.Prefer("return=representation")
    request.RequestBody(New OrderActionRequest())
    Dim response = Task.Run(Async Function() Await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request)).Result

    If d Then
        Dim result = response.Result(Of Order)()
        Debug.WriteLine($"Status: {result.Status}")
        Debug.WriteLine($"Order Id: {result.Id}")
        Debug.WriteLine($"Intent: {result.CheckoutPaymentIntent}")
        Debug.WriteLine("Links:")

        For Each link As LinkDescription In result.Links
            Debug.WriteLine(vbTab & $"{link.Rel}: {link.Href}" & vbTab & $"Call Type: {link.Method}")
        Next

        Debug.WriteLine("Capture Ids: ")

        For Each purchaseUnit As PurchaseUnit In result.PurchaseUnits

            For Each capture As Capture In purchaseUnit.Payments.Captures
                Debug.WriteLine(vbTab & $" {capture.Id}")
            Next
        Next

        Dim amount As AmountWithBreakdown = result.PurchaseUnits(0).AmountWithBreakdown
        Debug.WriteLine("Buyer:")
        Debug.WriteLine(vbTab & $"Email Address: {result.Payer.Email}" & vbLf & vbTab & $"Name: {result.Payer.Name.GivenName} {result.Payer.Name.Surname}" & vbLf)
        Debug.WriteLine($"Response JSON:" & vbLf & $"{PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result)}")
    End If

    Return response
End Function
```

Comment: It is an interesting question, but how is formulated now it is at risk of closure because you ask to find some external resource for you. Instead provide your attempts to solve the webhook problem, even if it doesn't work. Someone could spot the problem and help you

Comment: to be honest when it comes to the payments i'm looking for the best practice to receive the messages from paypal, i can create my own webhook class but i'm looking for the best practice to create it, so my code now is only to create order and capture the return response

Comment: i added my codes of creating and capturing the orders

Comment: What you want is a two port controller.  One port that connects to the clients and second port that forwards the client data to the SDK and sends responses from SDK to clients.  It would be no different from a regular controller except the request from clients would be forwarded to the SDK and the responses from SDK would be sent to the clients.

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal Webhooks guide is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#verify-event-notifications

The Webhooks API reference is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/

The PayPal REST SDKs that are mentioned for webhooks are no longer maintained, so you should NOT use any SDK. Instead, implement direct HTTPS API calls from your environment.

Comment: thanks for your response,I was able to find these documentations, actually what I'm looking for is a sample code of how to build the webhook with .net

Answer (score 0):

Just create a controller with the appropriate methods and routing
e.g.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController: ControllerBase 
{


   // point the webhook at .CancelUrl = "https://XXX/api/CancelUrl" (to match the routing)

  [HttpPost, Route("CancelUrl")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> CancelUrlAsync() 
  {
  // do cancel stuff here

  }

}
```